# PrimeFaces FileUpload queue size

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a situation where I need to upload multiple files.
The browse button will allow multiple selection and then it'll display the file list.
Then, another button will do the actual upload.

I want an error message whenever the user tries to upload more then 10 files.

The problem is that, when the user select more then 10 files (not necessarily all at once), I have a popup and I empty the file list but then every file over the 10th will be added to the list again. That should not happen, because I want the list to be emptied every time this exception is catched.

That's due to the fact that I can't manage to have a queue size or to empty it, so I'll never know if a file is the first of a set or the 11th.

```
   public void handleFileUpload(
                FileUploadEvent e) {

            e.getComponent().setTransient(false);

            //stuffstuffstuff

            try{
                if(list.size()>=webApplicationConst.getMultipleUploadFileLimit())
                    throw new FrontEndException("File limit exceeded", log);
                else
                    list.add(file);
            }
            catch(FrontEndException LimitExcedeed){
            list.clear();

 this.openWarningDialog(MessageConst.MESSAGE_WARNING_DIALOG_TITLE_LIMIT_EXCEDEED    );
            }

        }
```

Since onstart and oncomplite work for every file and not for every upload (still wondering why btw), is there a way to know the queue size, to empty it when I get the exception or to stop the whole uploading process without using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PrimeFaces 6.1 User Guide mentions the following attributes of p:fileUpload:

```
fileLimit          null   Integer   Maximum number of files allowed to upload.
fileLimitMessage   null   String    Message to display when file limit exceeds.
```

The fileLimitMessage gets shown when the user chooses more files than fileLimit, before the user hits "Upload".

If you want a more global limit, e.g. per session, then bind the fileLimit attribute to a property in your bean:

```
fileLimit="#{myBean.sessionFileLimit}"
```

When receiving uploads, in fileUploadListener decrement this limit accordingly. Update the p:fileUpload after uploads to update the limit on the client. Maybe even add `disabled="#{myBean.sessionFileLimit == 0}"` to disable fileUpload entirely, when the limit is reached.

Comment: The problem with those attributes is that they just prevent me from selecting more then N files. I still can select n-1 file twice thought, having the same problem :(

Comment: @pedro, then don't just set fileLimit to a static value. Bind it to a variable: `fileLimit="#{myBean.sessionOrUserOrWhateverfileLimit}"`. When receiving uploads decrement this limit. Update p:fileUpload after uploads to update the limit on the client. Maybe even add `disabled="#{myBean.sessionOrUserOrWhateverfileLimit == 0}"`.

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem neither. When the user tries to upload more then 10 files, I need it to clear the queue of both the file already uploaded and the remaining ones. The clearing is actually a feature and not a workaround.
If I follow your suggestion, the user might select 11 files and then have 10 of them uploaded without ever knowing anything went wrong.

Comment: @pedro, if the user selects more files than `fileLimit` then he will be shown big fat red `fileLimitMessage` before he hits "Upload". You can see it here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/multiple.xhtml

Comment: I was thinking again at your suggestion. If I set the fileLimit a actualFileLimit+1, it should work fine: I will still get the error message, the queue will be erased and I will not have 12th/13th/1nth file uploaded after the clearing.
Maybe that's what you meant the whole time and I just got you wrong xD
Anyway, my problem now is that the HandleFileUpload is in a class extended by the bean. How can I let the front end access a variable in a class extended by the bean?

Comment: Ok I fought with it a little and it looks like (sooner or later) it's going to work.
Should you post it as an answer I'll, vote it :)

Comment: How to update the p:fileUpload with the fileLimit value? I did not find any pointers to update a primefaces element's attribute. For instance, in the above example after decrementing the filesCounter, if I need to update the html with the update fileLimit value. how do I do it from mBean or within .xhtml file.

Comment: @Arvind, I meant update the component as usual, e.g. with `<p:ajax update="your_file_upload" />`.